# scheme not supported in URL, error when try to scrape image

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a image using ralger library in R.
Lamentably I get this error code: scheme not supported in URL.

example:

```
    library(ralger)

    setwd("C:/images")

    link= "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Jardillier"

    images_scrap(link, imgpath = getwd(), extn = "jpg" )

    Undefined Error: Error in download.file(img_urls_f[i], destfile = basename(img_urls_f[i]), : scheme not supported in URL '//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Robert_Jardillier_1932.jpg/220px-Robert_Jardillier_1932.jpg'

    [1] NA
```

Comment: That's how Wikimedia resources are (generally?) linked, without https scheme. Are you looking for a general solution for getting images from Wikipedia titles or is it more about ralger? It seems to provide simplistic interface for common tasks, which is perfectly fine until it just works but not much fun to work with once it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikimedia resources are (generally?) linked without the scheme, the `https:` part at the beginning of the URL. While it's perfectly valid for browsers, it can easily confuse scrapers and we'd need to add that part to the request ourselves. `ralger::images_scrap()`is pretty fixed and would need some awkward workarounds, but there's also `ralger::images_preview()` that just lists images and that list can be "fixed" before using it for downloading:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ralger)
link <- "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Jardillier"

# download files to ./img_ralger
dir.create("img_ralger")
images_preview(link) %>% 
  # [1] "/static/images/icons/wikipedia.png"                                                                                                                                        
  # [2] "/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-wordmark-fr.svg"                                                                                                                 
  # [3] "/static/images/mobile/copyright/wikipedia-tagline-fr.svg"                                                                                                                  
  # [4] "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Robert_Jardillier_1932.jpg/220px-Robert_Jardillier_1932.jpg" 
  # ...
  grep("\\.jpg$", ., value = TRUE) %>% 
  paste0("https:", .) %>%
  lapply(\(url_) download.file(url_, destfile = file.path("img_ralger", basename(url_)), mode = "wb"))
```

Wikipedia media resources can also be collected through API without scraping articles:

```r
wikipedia_jpg_list <- function(title_, loc_ = "fr"){
  media_list <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("https://",loc_,".wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/media-list/",title_))$items %>% as_tibble()
  media_list %>% 
    mutate(img_src = purrr::map_chr(srcset, ~ paste0("https:", .x$src[1]))) %>% 
    filter(grepl("\\.jpg$", img_src)) %>% 
    pull(img_src)
}

# download files to ./img_wikimedia_api
dir.create("img_wikimedia_api")
wikipedia_jpg_list("Robert_Jardillier") %>% 
  lapply(\(url_) download.file(url_, destfile = file.path("img_wikimedia_api", basename(url_)), mode = "wb"))
```